# SDL 2.0 windows 8 turn off alt+enter fullscreen

Tags: windows-8, sdl, fullscreen

I'm writing a game based on SDL 2.0 with OpenGL render. I need custom handling of fullscreen mode, but alt+enter on Windows 8 lead to forced fullscreen mode.

How can I turn off automatic turning on fullscreen mode via alt+enter on Windows 8?

How can I avoid toggling fullscreen mode via alt+enter on Windows 8 in general, not only using SDL 2.0?

Comment: Maybe when the window is put into fullscreen, catch that event and call SDL_SetWindowFullscreen to return to a windowed mode. For more info : http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowFullscreen

Comment: Thank you! But I think it will be a dirty trick )

Answer (score 2):

I have realised that via Direct3D I can do what I need:

```
IDXGIDevice * pDXGIDevice;
g_d3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void**)&pDXGIDevice);

IDXGIAdapter * pDXGIAdapter;
pDXGIDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void **)&pDXGIAdapter);

IDXGIFactory * pIDXGIFactory;
pDXGIAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void **)&pIDXGIFactory);
pIDXGIFactory->MakeWindowAssociation(g_hWnd, DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER);
```

Now I want to figure out how to get IDXGIFactory* in OpenGL code.

I tried to create new factory, enumerate adapters, but all adapters give me newly created factory which can't change any windowAssociations...

Comment: Where does `g_d3dDevice` come from?